Django - TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
I have looked at similar posts, but am really struggling with templates and urls.py - at least thats where I think my problem is.
I'm trying to use the default login page that comes with django. I get this error message, I've tried so many things but still cannot not get to work, can some please help?
This is the error message:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
registration/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://134.209.220.170/accounts/login/?next=/timwise/upload/
Django Version: 5.0
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
registration/login.html
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Raised during:  django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.10.12
Python Path:    
['/home/django/django_project',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 23 Oct 2024 01:53:02 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/django/django_project/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)

this is the template area of my settings.py:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,  "/home/django/django_project/templates"],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

this is my class view that is trying to redirect to the default django login page:
class FileUploadView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView): #entire class from gemini
    model = Files
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Create this template file
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success') # Define this url in urls.py

    def form_valid(self, form):
        file = form.save()
        filename = file.file.name 
        msg="file name is good"
        print('file loaded successfully')       
        messages.success(self.request, f"File '{filename}' uploaded successfully!")
        return redirect('success', filename=filename, msg=msg) #pass the filename as a url parameter


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # Handle form validation errors
        messages.error(self.request, "File upload failed. Please check the file and try again.")
        return super().form_invalid(form)

this is from my project level urls.py:
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import UploadHighlights, FileUploadView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
        path('upload/', FileUploadView.as_view(), name='upload'), # gemini
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        path('success/<str:filename>/<str:msg>/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='success.html'), name='success'),]

this is app level urls.py:
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import UploadHighlights, FileUploadView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
        path('upload/', FileUploadView.as_view(), name='upload'), # gemini
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        path('success/<str:filename>/<str:msg>/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='success.html'), name='success'),]


/home/django/django_project/templates/registration/login.html The error message says it tried to find the template as that file.  So, is that the correct place?  Does that file actually exist?

@john Gordon - maybe this is my ignorance, i thought since it was a built in template i didn't need to create a login.html file, so i was assuming it was an error with my templates directory.  Its strange to me because there are other admin views that I did not need to create, i thought the login page would be the same
